# Having trouble implementing custom oracle profile provider asp.net vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, profile, provider

I'm trying to implement a custom profile class for an ASP.net webforms oracle project.

Here's my base profile class using VB.net

```
Public Class BaseProfile
    Inherits ProfileBase

    Public Shared Function GetUserProfile(ByVal un As String) As BaseProfile
        Return TryCast(Create(un), BaseProfile)
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetUserProfile()
        Return TryCast(Create(Membership.GetUser().UserName), BaseProfile)
    End Function


    Public Property PreviousPage() As String
        Get
            Return TryCast(MyBase.Item("previouspage"), String)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            MyBase.Item("previouspage") = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Here's how I'm trying to use the class

```
        If userProfile Is Nothing Then
            userProfile = BaseProfile.GetUserProfile()

        End If

        userProfile.PreviousPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()
```

Here's how my web.config profile tag is set up

```
<profile defaultProvider="SqlProvider" inherits="AppNamespace.BaseProfile">
  <providers>
    <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="OraMembershipConnection"  applicationName="AppNamespace" />

   <add name="OraMembershipProvider" type="Oracle.Web.Profile.OracleProfileProvider",  Oracle.Web,  Culture=neutral" connectionStringName="OraMembershipConnection" ApplicationName="AppNamespace"/>
  </providers>

</profile>
```

When I use defaultProvider="SqlProvider", it allows me to create my BaseProfile class, but when I try to set a property I get an error that says

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

When I use defaultProvider="OraMembershipProvider", I get this error on class init

```
Provider must implement the class 'System.Web.Profile.ProfileProvider'. (C:\development\proj\web.config line 177)
```

I've tried to find documentation on this online. When I try to inherit BaseProfile with OracleProfileProvider then I can't use the Create functions anymore as they don't exist within that class.

I need some direction or advice on this to figure out what I'm doing wrong! Thanks.

Yes, "OraMembershipConnection" is a valid working connection that works for other parts of the project.